# Mathematical description of a scalar field $\phi(x^{\mu})$

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, quantum-interpretations

A quantum particle that has no spin, no charge, no interaction can be 'modelled' by $\phi(x^{\mu})$. This is a particle that moves freely; random one could say as well.

In classical mechanics if we have a field, we can find the particle in a certain point in spacetime. In quantum mechanics, we can only find the probability that the particle is found in a certain location in spacetime.

For simplicity: let's say we are in a 2D world with location on the y-axis and time on the x-axis. If one would snap a picture of this particle at a certain point in time; how would we describe that moment mathematically and the measurement of the location in probability?

It's kind of hard to explain what I have in mind;
I am trying to find a certain theoretical particle which is independent of others; so no interactions (that's why the Higgs boson is not suitable at this moment; I also have problems cooling the math down to 2 dimensions); but I then want to store the sequence of probabilities of the found locations. I am sorry if my question is not so clear; I had QFT I at the start of this year but then the virus came. Still hope someone can help me.

Comment: For clarification, not meaning to be pendantic, how can we "find" the particle if it does not interact? Some amount of scattering must be involved to detect it.

Answer (score 1):

QFT (quantum field theory) quantizes the classical fields, which are regarded as operators. A free real scalar field $\phi (x)$ is described as a mode expansion, which in the Schroedinger picture shows
$$
\phi (\vec x) = \int \frac{d^3p}{(2 \pi)^3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 E_p}} \left(a (\vec p) e^{i \vec p \cdot \vec x} + a^\dagger (\vec p) e^{-i \vec p \cdot \vec x}\right)
$$
where $a (\vec p)$ is the annihilation operator and $a^\dagger (\vec p)$ is the creation operator.

The field $\phi (\vec x)$ acting on the vacuum $\vert 0 \rangle$ creates a one-particle state in $\vec x$ position.

A realistic particle, i.e. a particle localized in a limited spacetime region, can be described as a Gaussian wave packet. The definite momenta states compounding the field $\phi (\vec x)$ to be modulated by a Gaussian profile. In this way the approximations both in space and momentum are related by the uncertainty principle.